# Not able to connect to Bluehost server for reading mail from PHP script using imap_open

Tags: php, imap, bluehost

I am trying to connect to Bluehost to read my email (on one of the domains on Bluehost). I tried the following code:

```
imap_open("{mail.domain.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $email, $password);
```

and also tried

```
imap_open("{box***.bluehost.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $email, $password);

imap_open("{box***.bluehost.com:995/imap/ssl}INBOX", $email, $password);
```

but it shows connection timed out error.

I have checked using phpinfo(), imap and ssl support is enabled.

I have used ports, 995, 993 110 and 143.

I use Microsoft Outlook as my email client. I tried to get details from Outlook and that shows the server as pop3 server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dedicated IP? You might also want to check you PHP INI file if IMAP is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mailboxpath = '{boxXXX.bluehost.com:143/imap}';
$username = 'a@b.c';
$password = '?????';

$imap = imap_open($mailboxpath, $username, $password);


$folders = imap_list($imap, $mailboxpath, "*");

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($folders as $folder)
{
        $folder = str_replace($mailboxpath, "", imap_utf7_decode($folder));
        echo '<li><a href="mail.php?folder=' . $folder . '&func=view">' . $folder . '</a></li>';
print "\n";
}
echo "</ul>";
```